# Cannot render the template because of an error.: YAMLException

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to deploy a aws cloudformation stack but it gives me this error' Cannot render the template because of an error.: YAMLException: duplicated mapping key at line 63, column 5: DataCenterPublicSubnet: ^'
How do I resolve this issue?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Metadata:
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Interface':
    ParameterGroups:
      - Label:
          default: Extract Predict Part 1 - File Server resource deployment
        Parameters:
          - VPC
          - Subnet
          - KeyName
          - SecurityGroupIds
          - LatestLinuxAmiId
Parameters:
  EnvironmentName: DE-Extract
  Description: An environment name that is prefixed to resource names
  Type: String
  VpcCIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.0.0/16

  DataCenterPublicSubnetCIDR:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.10.0/24

  VPC:
    Description: VPC to deploy resources into.
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC::Id'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCIDR
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
  Subnet:
    Description: Subnet to deploy resources into.
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id'
  SecurityGroupIds:
    Description: Specify the security group/s for resources.
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>'
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the file server.
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
    ConstraintDescription: Must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
  LatestLinuxAmiId:
    Description: Do Not modify the below default value!
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2
Resources:
    InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
    InternetGatewayAttachment:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
    DataCenterPublicSubnet:
     Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref DataCenterPublicSubnetCIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub DE-Extract Data Center Subnet
    PrivateRouteTable:
     Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub DE-Extract Public Routes
    DefaultPrivateRoute:
     Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway
    DataCenterPublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
     Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet
    LinuxInstance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref LatestLinuxAmiId
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref s3ROInstanceProfile
      SecurityGroupIds: !Ref SecurityGroupIds
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: DE-Extract-Linux-Instance
      UserData: !Base64
        'Fn::Join':
          - ''
          - - |
              #!/bin/bash
            - |
              yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
            - |
              sudo su
            - |
              mkdir /temp
            - |
              aws s3 sync s3://de-extract-predict-payload/Pre_Script /temp
            - |
              chmod 755 /temp/prescript.sh
            - |
              cd /temp
            - |
              ./prescript.sh
            - |
              rm prescript.sh
    s3ROInstanceProfile:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile'
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - !Ref s3ROrole
    s3ROAccessPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
    Properties:
      PolicyName: s3ROAccessPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 's3:Get*'
              - 's3:List*'
            Resource: '*'
      Roles:
        - !Ref s3ROrole
    s3ROrole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
Outputs:
  LinuxInstance:
  Description: Private IP address of the newly created File server EC2 instance
    Value: !GetAtt
      - LinuxInstance
      - PrivateIp
```

Answer (score 0):

All **indentation** in your template is incorrect. You have to make sure that your template is properly intended before you try to create a stack from it.